# std::remove does not work when passing index

Tags: c++, stl

The goal of my test program is to erase a cell in a simple vector of strings like below.
The program fail (segmentation fault).

```
static void display(std::vector<std::string> const &vec)
{
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator It = vec.begin();
    for (; It != vec.end(); ++It)
        std::cout << *It << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int         main(void)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    size_t  index = 0;

    vec.push_back("Toto");
    vec.push_back("Titi");
    vec.push_back("Tata");
    vec.push_back("Tutu");

    display(vec);

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator It = vec.begin();

    for (size_t idx = 0; It != vec.end(); ++It, idx++)
        if (!(*It).compare("Tutu"))
            index = idx;

    vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), index), vec.end()); //Segmentation fault

    display(vec);

    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Does anyone can help me? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't you need to pass a string to `remove`?

Comment: Read about the arguments to `remove` more carefully. It does not take an index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), index), vec.end());
```

You need to pass the actual element (in this case of type `std::string`) to your `erase` function.

So instead of `index`, it should be `somestring`

Comment: I'm confused, why do you need to use erase aswell as remove?

cppreference.com says: 1) Removes all elements that are equal to value.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Answer (score 0):

- you shall not mix iterators and homebrew indices. use the iterators only.
- algorithms like copy - there are external algorithms for use when you want to decouple from the actual container type and there are member functions that do an optimized job. in your case vec erase does everhting for you, just pass the found iterator

  vec.erase(It);

Answer (score 0):

Since you're checking for equality, just use `std::remove`:

```
vec.erase( std::remove( vec.begin(), vec.end(), "Tutu" ),
           vec.end() );
```

It's the standard idiom.  If for some reason, you have to write
the loop yourself:

```
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator current = vec.begin();
while ( current != vec.end() ) {
    if ( *current == "Tutu" ) {
        current = vec.erase( current ) ;
    } else {
        ++ current;
    }
}
```

(Again, the standard idiom.)