# Wrong character removing using std::remove

Tags: c++, string, std, cut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove spaces from std::string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c)
>   [std::remove does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661355/stdremove-does-not-work)

I use std::remove to remove some charaters from the string.
For example:

```
std::string hash_value = "3f-2b-d6-ab-aa-6d-62-b4-ce-6f-6b-2f-21-4c-99-fc";
std::remove(hash_value.begin(), hash_value.end(), '-');
```

After this `hash_value` size must be 32 and have value:

> 3F2BD6ABAA6D62B4CE6F6B2F214C99FC

But it 47 size and value:

> 3F2BD6ABAA6D62B4CE6F6B2F214C99FC-2F-21-4C-99-FC

Can you help me, what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [remove-erase idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom). std::remove only moves elements to the end of container, you need to erase them afterwards.

try

```
hash_value.erase(std::remove(hash_value.begin(), hash_value.end(), '-'), hash_value.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

[std::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) rearranges the contents of a sequence so that the "removed" elements are at the end, where end is defined as the range between the iterator returned by the function, and the end of the sequence. If you want to make your sequence shorter, use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

```
hash_value.erase(std::remove(hash_value.begin(), hash_value.end(), '-'), hash_value.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

The function cannot alter the properties of the object containing the range of elements (i.e., it cannot alter the size of an array or a container): The removal is done by replacing the elements that compare equal to val by the next element that does not, and signaling the new size of the shortened range by returning an iterator to the element that should be considered its new past-the-end element.

For example look at below example related to std::remove

int myints[] = {10,20,30,30,20,10,10,20};      // 10 20 30 30 20 10 10 20

// bounds of range:

int* pbegin = myints;                          // ^

int* pend = myints+sizeof(myints)/sizeof(int);

// pend points to container (logical) end now

pend = std::remove (pbegin, pend, 20);

std::cout << "range contains:";

for (int* p=pbegin; p!=pend; ++p)

std::cout << ' ' << *p;

It will display

range contains: 10 30 30 10 10